C# Reflection Property Getter using Compiled Expressions
I want to create a compiled expression instead of using reflection directly for getting properties of objects.
Using reflection will be some like this. Is it possible to create an equivalent compiled expression?
Func<object, string, object> func = (obj, propName) =>
{
    var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
    var value = prop?.GetValue(obj, null);
    return value;
};


Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression

I want this code in compiled expression due to efficiency, as you can see I want to build a property value getter, not propery name

Have you read the example of Expression.Property?

You can build your own Expression to get the property of the object:
Expression<Func<T, TResult>> GetExpression<T, TResult>(string propName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propName);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(property, parameter);
} 

And you could test it like below:
var tc = new TestClass()
{
    Name = "test name"
};

var predicate = GetExpression<TestClass, string>(nameof(TestClass.Name));
var compiled = predicate.Compile();
Console.WriteLine(compiled(tc));

Reference: Build expression trees

Thanks for your reply! This will create an expression for getting the propery of a defined type of objects. That right? My func was for every type of object. So the key is saving one func per each type of object. That's right?

@JuanDYB I am not sure what you mean..
